# How to get all documents in Firestore (v9) sub collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get all documents in all sub-collection with Firebase V9, so I used collectionGroup to retrieve the data.

Here is my Firestore architecture :

```
bots (collection)
    | id (doc ID)
        | order_history (sub collection)
            | id (doc ID)
                createdBy: uid (user uid)
```

[image]

And this is how I try to get documents :

```
const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
const { user } = useAuth();

const getOrders = async () => {
    const orders = await getDocs(query(collectionGroup(db, 'order_history'), where('createdBy', '==', user.uid)));
setOrders(orders.docs.map((doc) => ({
  ...doc.data()
})))
  }

useEffect(() => {
    getOrders();
    console.log('orders ', orders); // return []
}, []);
```

This code returns an empty array.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: The functions seems to be working correct. Firestore returns data asynchronously so the log runs before your data is retrieved. Try mapping the orders array into your component or logging data in `getOrders()` function itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `getOrders` function is asynchronus function.
If you want debug `log` I think you should waiting for getOrders  `completed` then `orders` had been updated.

Ex:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('orders ', orders);
}, [orders]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your getOrders anonymous method execution requires an explicit return statement if there's more than 1 statement. Implicit returns work when only a single statement exists (and after some testing, `return await X` doesn't appear to work either).

```
const getOrders = async () => {
    const orders = await getDocs(...);
    setOrders(orders.docs.map(...))
}
```

Needs to be

```
const getOrders = async () => {
    const orders = await getDocs(...);
    return setOrders(orders.docs.map(...))
}
```